# how to show choice list or select option in symfony2 using the dynamic data

Tags: php, symfony

I want to create a contact form "contactformType" for where I have to show some select box like below.

```
<select id="categoryId" name="categoryID" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Please select a Category</option>            
    <option value="0">Full</option>            
    <option value="1">Half</option>            
    <option value="2">Almost empty</option>
</select>
```

from a model or entity "category".

how do I get the dynamic data in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is truly a Doctrine Entity that you're trying to get the data from, you can do this in your form class 'contactformType', buildForm method (this will automatically create a 'choice' field type from an entity):

```
$builder->add( 'category', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'YourBundle:Category', 'choice_label' => 'displayFieldName',
    'query_builder' => function( CategoryRepository $repository ){ 
        return $repository->createQueryBuilder('c')->orderBy( 'c.displayFieldName', 'ASC' );
    }
) );
```

Don't forget to `use` your CategoryRepository class as well.

Comment: Please explain me from where i will get the CategoryRepository

Comment: You write it ... didn't you create a Category Entity?

Comment: I am writing below code but getting error 

Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Form\TtpContentType::AppBundle\Form\{closure}() must be an instance of AppBundle\Form\TtpCategory, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository given 

->add( 'categoryId', 'entity', array(
 'class' => 'AppBundle:TtpCategory', 'choice_label' => 'name',
 'query_builder' => function( TtpCategory $repository ){ 
  return $repository->createQueryBuilder('c')->orderBy( 'c.name', 'ASC' );
 }
) )

Comment: No ... a repository is a separate class.  In this case, it would be TtpCategoryRepository ... and it's a good idea to create them - even if they're empty (because it lets you do tricky things like this).  You COULD use the base EntityRepository class instead, but it's not good practice - [EntityRepository Class](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html)

Comment: Here are the Symfony docs: [Databases and Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes)

Comment: Hang on ... just saw the error you posted.  So, did you create TtpCategory as a repository rather than an entity? (there are very good reasons for following naming conventions - you've just proven one of them)

Comment: yes.. it working... I have some 2 more issue. Can you please share the email id so i can mail you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90099/discussion-between-dinesh-k-and-ragdata).